# Flexbox: Autoprefixer adding a css property that is breaking Safari

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

When I add

```
   display: flex;
```

To my container div, autoprefixer (I'm using Grunt with "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.3") adds:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
```

The problem is, my layout breaks in Safari with

```
  display: -webkit-box;
```

If I leave it display: -webkit-flex all is well. Any thoughts on how to disable this?

Comment: What does "breaks" mean? Can you include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry, meaning: boxes are positioned outside of container. It turns out that I need to change the order of -webkit-box (used for older browsers) and -webkit-flex. -webkit-flex should be last or else Safari reads the older version.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster kind of answered this in their comment, but just to review, Safari (8 anyway) wants `-webkit-flex`, which autoprefixer isn't spitting out depending on your settings (or maybe at all, I didn't actually try tinkering with the settings). If your CSS looks like:

```
display:flex;
display:-webkit-flex;
```

it seems to fix it, as the autoprefixer output will now be:

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

Same for any other flexbox properties, so:

```
display:flex;
display:-webkit-flex;
flex-direction:column;
-webkit-flex-direction:column;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content:center;
```